# If two topological spaces X,Y are contractible then they have the same homotopy type

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let X, Y be contractible spaces (i.e $id_X$ and $id_Y$ are nullhomotopic). Then, X and Y have the same homotopy type (i.e $\exists f: X \rightarrow Y$ homotopy equivalence) .

Since X,Y are contractible $\exists x_0 \in X,y_0 \in Y$ such that for the constant maps $c_{x_0}:X \rightarrow \{x_0\}$ and $c_{y_0}:Y \rightarrow \{y_0\}$ it holds : $id_X$ is homotopic to $c_{x_0}$ and $id_Y$ is homotopic to $c_{y_0}$.

How do I proceed with finding the homotopy equivalence f? I haven't yet dealt with fundamental groups so I was wondering if there is a way to just write down a formula for f.

Comment: Any two one-point spaces are homeomorphic.  Now transitivity.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to. $X$ contractible means having the same homotopy type as a one-point space.

So $X$ has that homotopy type, and $Y$ too. Having the same homotopy type is an equivalence relation, so transitive, and we’re done.

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for, I proved with the definitions I have (and wrote at the question above): 1) If X is contractible then X has the same homotopy type as a one-point space ,2) Having the same homotopy type defines an equivalence relation and 3) Two one-point spaces have the same homotopy type. I think all 3 above needed some proof (with the definitions provided) and they imply easily what I wanted.

Comment: @WalterWhite there is really only one one-point space, so I’m not sure the third needs proof. The first is immediate from the definition and the middle one should be in your text/notes too.

Comment: All of them are easy to prove , but it's the first time I'm dealing with these so I try to prove everything rigorously. In the third I proved it (of course the proof is almost trivial) because X being contractible would give the same homotopy type of X with some one point space and Y being contractible would give the same homotopy type of Y with some (possibly other) one point space and I wasn't sure how to use rigorously the fact that there exists only one one-point space (which I understand intuitively) .  Anyway your answer helped me figure these out, thanks!